# Set PostgreSQL pager to less?

Tags: postgresql, pager

I'm trying to get my psql pager output to look nicer.

I've added the following to my ~/.bashrc

```
export PAGER='less -S'
```

And I've added these line to my ~/.psqlrc

```
\x auto
\pset pager on
\setenv PAGER less
```

Current output:

[image: Current pager output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired pager output]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\setenv PAGER less` in `.psqlrc` overwrites the environment variable with an undesirable different value (without the `-S` option).

Either remove it, or change it to `\setenv PAGER 'less -S'`, or create a new environment variable `LESS` set to `-S`

Note that even when `less` is not called with the `-S / --chop-long-lines` option, hitting the right arrow key will scroll horizontally and temporarily display lines without wrapping them.

Comment: Make sure to use single quotes for `'less -S'`

Comment: See also `\pset`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474138/customize-pager-in-psql.

Comment: Here I am finding a solution to a question that I already asked 5 years ago. Wild!